# Ostream unidentified?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, ofstream

So I have this header file that has 2 functions which utilize ostream
and I am trying to overload the indirection operator (<<) to allow me to write to a file using a pointer that is pointing to a templated list node.

from the .h file here are the prototypes

```
void PrintForward(ostream &out);
void PrintBackward(ostream &out);
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, List<t> const* p);
```

then from the .cpp file

Operator overloading function

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, ListNode::List const* p)
{
    return out << *p;
}
```

Printforward function

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::PrintForward(ostream &out)
{
    ListNode* lp = head;

while(lp != NULL)
{
    out << *lp->value;
    lp = lp -> next;
}
}
```

Printbackward Function

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::PrintBackward(ostream &out)
{
    ListNode* lp = tail;

    while(lp != NULL)
    {
        out << *lp;
        lp = lp -> prev;
    }
}
```

Currently all I get is a compiler error saying

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'
```

but I cannot find it. Before I switched all the functions into the .cpp file I was getting a different error stating use of class template requires template argument list. But it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Do you have an `#include <ostream>`? Also, if you don't have `using namespace std` up the top (which you shouldn't), it should be `std::ostream`.

Comment: "there is a syntax error with ostream" I find it hard to believe that is exactly what your compiler says. Post the exact error, and also which line it occurs at.

Comment: @Yuushi I actually had #include<fstream> which if I am not mistaken includes ostream as well. I did swap it out and rebuild only to get a much larger list of errors as well.

Comment: @stijn this is the error I currently get 
 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see many problems in this code:
Your declaration of the operator<< is using a template class t, but there is not a declaration of this template class, like

```
template<class t>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, List<t> const* p);
```

Also the declaration and the definition of these function are not equals in the second parameter:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, List<t> const* p);
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, ListNode::List const* p)
```

Finally, I don't know from your code if you are using the namespace std, in the case is not, then you must write std:: before ostream class, like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, List<t> const* p);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, ListNode::List const* p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted all the code, but I notice you are not qualifying ostream with std:

```
//.h
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, List<t> const* p);

//.cpp
//...
// Either qualify with std, or bring it into scope by using namespace std...
```